# vnstat: Statistics of two connected OpenVPN-interfaces differ

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have two servers connected over an OpenVPN tunnel. The tunnel is a 1-to-1 tunnel with fixed IPs, so there should be no one else talking over the same tunnel interfaces than these servers.

Some days ago I installed vnstat on both machines. Today I checked out the statistics, but not all values are clear to me:

**Statistics on OpenVPN server:**

```
# vnstat -i tun1 -d

 tun1  /  daily

     day         rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
 ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
  05/10/15     21.86 MiB |  372.29 MiB |  394.15 MiB |   37.37 kbit/s
  05/11/15     28.81 MiB |  416.85 MiB |  445.66 MiB |   42.26 kbit/s
  05/12/15     30.03 MiB |  483.22 MiB |  513.24 MiB |   48.66 kbit/s
  05/13/15     30.44 MiB |  495.93 MiB |  526.38 MiB |   49.91 kbit/s
  05/14/15     12.44 MiB |   19.64 MiB |   32.08 MiB |    4.42 kbit/s
 ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
 estimated        17 MiB |      27 MiB |      44 MiB |
```

**Statistics on OpenVPN client:**

```
# vnstat -i tun0 -d

 tun0  /  daily

     day         rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
 ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
  05/10/15      1.72 GiB |  120.65 MiB |    1.84 GiB |  178.85 kbit/s
  05/11/15    418.54 MiB |   31.09 MiB |  449.63 MiB |   42.63 kbit/s
  05/12/15    952.97 MiB |   54.33 MiB |    0.98 GiB |   95.51 kbit/s
  05/13/15    986.44 MiB |   68.35 MiB |    1.03 GiB |  100.01 kbit/s
  05/14/15    509.69 MiB |   38.43 MiB |  548.12 MiB |   76.50 kbit/s
 ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
 estimated       749 MiB |      55 MiB |     804 MiB |
```

The stats on 05/10/15 may differ because I did not install vnstat at the same time on both hosts. So, let's start on 05/11/15: The statistics on both hosts nearly match, so they look good to me.

But now the problem: On 05/12/15, there is a big difference between both statistics. The client says it received about 1GB of data whereas the server says only 0.5GB have been sent. Furthermore, the client says 55MB have been sent but the server only received 30MB.

Any idea, what could cause this differences?

*EDIT:* Some additional information...

- Version on both systems: OpenVPN 2.2.1
- The client runs inside a VirtualBox VM
- Both machines run Debian 7.6 Wheezy